# HDFS ACL | Unable to define ACL automatically for child folders

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have following scenario. There is parent folder /user with five child folder as test1 , test2, test3 etc in HDFS.

```
/user/test1
/user/test2
/user/test3
```

I applied acl on parent folder to make sure user has automatically access to child folder.

```
 hdfs dfs -setfacl -m default:user:shashi:rwx /user
```

but when i try to put some file , it is giving permission denied exception

```
hadoop fs -put test.txt  /user/test3
put: Permission denied: user=shashi, access=WRITE, inode="/user/test3":hdfs:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x
```

**getfacl output**

```
hadoop fs -getfacl /user/test3
# file: /user/test3
# owner: hdfs
# group: supergroup
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Any pointers on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you please try with -R option in the -setfacl command? Its not applying the ACLs recursively in the above command you provided. Thanks